# toggleDrawer from @react-navigation/drawer not working in React-Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-drawer

I made a nested navigation Drawer + Stack, but the drawer is not working, I am not able to toggle the drawer, but able to drag the drawer from the left side and it goes back closing automatically after releasing it.

Also, I get a pop up when hovering over `navigation.toggleDrawer()`, this is what I get

> Property 'toggleDrawer' does not exist on type
> 'NavigationProp<ParamListBase, string, Readonly<{ key: string; index:
> number; routeNames: string[]; history?: unknown[]; routes:
> NavigationRoute<ParamListBase, string>[]; type: string; stale: false;
> }>, {}, {}>'

So what's wrong here and how to fix it? And can I make a drawer without using `@react-navigation/drawer` ?

**app.js :**

```js
import React from "react";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import HomeScreen from "./src/screens/HomeScreen";
import MovieScreen from "./src/screens/MovieScreen";
import FavoriteScreen from "./src/screens/FavoritesScreen";
import { useFonts } from "expo-font";
import AppLoading from "expo-app-loading";
import { createDrawerNavigator } from "@react-navigation/drawer";
import CustomDrawerContent from "./src/components/DrawerContent";

const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

function HomeStackScreen() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen
        name='home'
        component={HomeScreen}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name='movie'
        component={MovieScreen}
        options={{ headerShown: false }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

export default () => {
  const [fontLoaded] = useFonts({
    Regular: require("./assets/fonts/NunitoSans-Regular.ttf"),
    Bold: require("./assets/fonts/NunitoSans-Bold.ttf"),
    Black: require("./assets/fonts/NunitoSans-Black.ttf"),
    ExtraBold: require("./assets/fonts/NunitoSans-ExtraBold.ttf"),
    ExtraLight: require("./assets/fonts/NunitoSans-ExtraLight.ttf"),
    Light: require("./assets/fonts/NunitoSans-Light.ttf"),
    SemiBold: require("./assets/fonts/NunitoSans-SemiBold.ttf"),
  });

  return fontLoaded ? (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator
        drawerContent={(props) => <CustomDrawerContent {...props} />}
        initialRouteName='Home'
        screenOptions={{ drawerPosition: "left", drawerType: "front" }}
      >
        <Drawer.Screen
          name='home'
          component={HomeStackScreen}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
        <Drawer.Screen
          name='fav'
          component={FavoriteScreen}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  ) : (
    <AppLoading />
  );
};
```

**home.js**

```js
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";

export default function HomeScreen(){
const navigation = useNavigation();
return(
<ScrollView style={styles.container}>
        <StatusBar
          style='auto'
          translucent={false}
          backgroundColor={COLORS.BASIC_BACKGROUND}
        />
        <View
          style={{
            flexDirection: "row",
            justifyContent: "space-between",
            alignItems: "center",
            paddingHorizontal: 20,
            paddingVertical: 10,
          }}
        >
          <Pressable
            style={{ flex: 1 }}
            onPress={() => {
              navigation.toggleDrawer();
              console.log("Clicked on Menu Bar");
            }}
          >
            <Image
              style={{ width: 25, height: 28 }}
              source={{
                uri: "https://img.icons8.com/material-rounded/96/000000/menu--v1.png",
              }}
            />
          </Pressable>
        </View>
</ScrollView>
)
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @PeterOla No I didn't